# How do i map a javascript object to a class and remove unwanted properties in it

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I am using Typescript to be precise and ExpressJS for creating API.

Suppose I have a typescript User model:

```
class UserModel {
    id: number;
    email: string;
    password: string;
    name: string;
    dob: Date;
    gender: UserGender;
    connections: UserModel[]
}

enum UserGender {
    "MALE" = 1,
    "FEMALE" = 2,
    "OTHER" = 3
}
```

I want to restrict the object to send only those properties that are included in the response object class i.e

```
class ConnectionResponse {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    email: string;
    dob: Date,
    gender: UserGender;
}

class UserConnectionsResponse {
    id: number;
    connections: ConnectionResponse[];
}
```

This class excludes some of the properties such as `password` in `ConnectionResponse` which should be mapped to `UserModel`

and

`UserConnectionResponse` should also be mapped to `UserModel` but only the `id` and `connections` fields.

Is there any package or a generic way to map all of the Models I am getting from the database to the response objects and include only the properties which are present in the response object instead of the whole model?

P.S: I don't want to implement this manually by looping through both the classes and deleting properties manually. Please suggest some other workarounds such as a package or any other thing.

Comment: What you mean by "_UserConnectionResponse should also be mapped to UserModel_"?

Comment: @palaѕн sorry for the weak English. What i mean is the UserModel will be returned by the database query and then i want to map that UserModel to this UserConnectionResponse such that the properties that are not in this response object should not be sent as the response from the API.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a generic assign function like this.

```js
function assign(target: any, origin: any) {
  let keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(target);
  keys.forEach(key => {
    target [key] = origin[key]
  });
}

let source: UserModel = getUserModel();
let dest: UserConnectionsResponse = new UserConnectionsResponse();
assign(dest, source);
```